# ReactJS - unable to fetch from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So what I am trying to do is do send some data by clicking a submit button (A mathematical expression) to a Django-API. There this expression is processed and a new expression is returned to another textbox. I am trying to do this in a single function. The Post requests are working perfectly fine which I have checked through the Postman application.

I am unable to fetch the processed data from the API. I am getting the following error -->
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/differentiate/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

The overview of the application -->
[image: Overview]

The code for my function is ->

```
async postData() {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/differentiate/';
        let result = await fetch(url,{
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                functiondata: this.fx
            })
        }); 
        fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                fprimex: JSON.stringify(json)
            })
        }) 
        
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that and now another error has appeared. I've updated my post accordingly. Please see

Comment: **405 Method not allowed** means (in your case) server is not expecting a GET request, maybe POST or PUT. You need to check with your backend guy.